# What model of aircraft is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

So, what type of airplane is it?

Comment: Where did you get this photo and why is it so oddly cropped?

Comment: I don't know. Friend sent it to me.

Comment: It's from Tumblr apparently.

Comment: I prefer the uncropped image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's an [Antonov An-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2).

> [It] is a Soviet mass-produced single-engine biplane utility/agricultural aircraft designed (...) in 1946. Its remarkable durability, high lifting power, and ability to take off and land from poor runways have given it a long service life. The An-2 is still produced and remains in service with military and civilian operators around the world.

[Original image here](https://500px.com/photo/108103615/airplane1-by-micha%C5%82-dankowski) (no description though).

[image]
([commons.wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:An2_cockpit_1.jpg))

[image]
([commons.wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:An-2_OK-HFL_EDST_02.jpg))

Comment: It is "huge" for a biplane. Look at the number of windows in the passenger cabin (one window for each of the 12 passengers...)

Comment: Side question: anybody know which airlines hostesses wear polka? Lol.